# Hide HTML outside of canvas element in the JavaScript tool InfoVis

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, data-visualization, infovis

I'm currently creating a visualization of some objects on my project and I'm using the [InfoVis toolkit](http://thejit.org/) to handle the graph visualization part. So far I have the nodes plotted correctly and relating to each other correctly, but there is a graphical error that is bothering me. When a node is partly off of the canvas, the background of the node is hidden (as it should be) because it is a canvas element itself. However, the contents (which are HTML) are shown completely and they hang off of the canvas element.

You can see the visualization here: [Link](http://107.21.100.110/relate.php)

Drag around the graph until one of the nodes is partly off the screen and you'll see it. It is more obvious on the right/bottom sides.

Here is a picture of the problem: The black border is the canvas border.

How can I stop this from happening?

[image: The black border is the canvas border]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `overflow: hidden` on the div with the ID `infovis-canvaswidget`. It looks like the Canvas element is injected into it.

[image]

Comment: @JasonKaczmarsky - Happens to everyone. Glad to help.

Comment: rad, glad nothing any more complex.